# C# array access issue

Tags: c#, arrays

I am using `Asp.net/C#` ,, i have declared an `integer` `array` as follows `public int[] recno;`
As i dont know the exact size of the `array` ,, however inside a `function` i get to know its size  based on the number of `customer_id's` in the table.Here is the `function`

```
public void GetRecordNo()
        {
            recid = from id in dt.cust_masters
                    select id;
            recno = new int[recid.Count()];

            for (int i = 0; i < recid.Count(); i++)
            {
                recno[i] = Convert.ToInt32(recid.ElementAt(i).customer_id);
            }

        }
```

When i try to call a function `ShowRecord(int index)` which accepts the `id` of the customer in the following manner

```
ShowRecord(recno[0])
```

It gives me an error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Can anybody point me where am i going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there your query returns values?

Comment: try using "from cust in dt.cust_masters select cust.id;"

Comment: @Maheep it does return value because when i call the function ShowRecord() inside that function it works well ..

Comment: what happens if you call ShowRecord(recno[1])

Comment: @KOL it gives me the same error , which i mentioned in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code:

```
recid = from id in dt.cust_masters
          select id.customer_id;

//recno = new int[recid.Count()];
recno = recid.ToArray();
// remove for-loop
```

And to find/prevent your null ref problem:

```
void  ShowRecord(int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= recno.Length)
       throw new InvalidArgumentException("index");

    var id = recno[index];
    ...
}
```

Comment: ,,,, but will that allow me to access values of recno outside that function

Comment: That depends on how `public` / `private` you make `recno[]`. Not on this method. But what is the actual question ?

Comment: ,, i have made it public , my question is that i need the values of the array to be passed as parameters to ShowRecord() function.

Answer (score 3):

Why can you just use:

```
public void GetRecordNo()
{
    var recno=(
        from id in dt.cust_masters
        select id.customer_id
    ).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: then how do i pass id's to my function

Answer (score 1):

First check which object is null by setting a breakpoint and hovering over the parameter recno of `ShowRecord(recno[0])`. Is it null? If yes, make sure your GetRecordNo() method is actually being called before your call to ShowRecord.

Or use this to access recno:

```
public int[] RecNo {
    get {
        if (recno == null) { GetRecNo(); }
        return recno;
    }
}
```

and then use it like

```
ShowRecord(RecNo[0])
```

Comment: ,, i call GetRecordNo() on load and im calling ShowRecord on click of a button , do you think this might be issue.

Comment: the issue was exactly what you pointed out ,,, when i called GetRecordNo() and then ShowRecord() ,, it worked fine ,,, so will i have to call it again n again ...Thanks

Comment: @freebird Maybe you are accessing a local variable rather than your public field? I edited my post, maybe it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked well for me ,,,, if you could do a favour , could you please explain me how it works.Thanks

Comment: It checks if recno is null, and if it is, it calls GetRecNo(). That way, if you access the property RecNo, you never get null. But i think that your load method (where you said you call GetRecNo()) might not get called if recno is still null at this point.

Comment: what i fail to understand is i call GetRecNo() on load and ShowRecord() on click of button , this gives error , button on click of the button if i call GetRecNo() first and then ShowRecord() , it works well , what could be the issue.

Comment: Is the load method called? You could place a breakpoint at your first call to GetRecNo to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I think, `ShowRecord(int index)` contains a parameter which includes int index but when you are calling function,you are using `ShowRecord(recno[0])` which means you are passing `recno` record at `index 0`.......